# What will be the reading of a barometer inside an airtight box?

Tags: pressure

Suppose that I enclose a barometer inside an airtight (but not vacuum) box. Will the pressure reading change?

Comment: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!" from how to ask a good question https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Some comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68399/discussion-on-question-by-siva-manasan-what-will-be-the-reading-of-a-barometer-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it can change.** This depends on how deformable the walls are, but no matter how strong, if the external pressure is high enough then the walls will bend inward and compress the air inside, raising the internal pressure as measured by the barometer.

As usual, it's useful to consider the limiting cases to examine this behaviour.

- On one side, suppose that your 'air sealed box' is simply an impermeable membrane, maybe hung on a wooden frame or something. Then if the atmospheric pressure increases, this will be transferred to the inside.
- On the opposite side, suppose that you make a sturdy metal chamber where the walls themselves resist deformation. In this case, then everyday changes in atmospheric pressure are unlikely to change the internal pressure much, but one can turn things up quantitatively (but not qualitatively!) by submersing the box to the bottom of the ocean. There the external pressure won't crush the box (we hope) but it will compress some parts slightly, and that will raise the internal pressure as measured by the barometer.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like a submarine? The outside pressure is in the hundreds of atm, but there's only one inside. So technically, it depends on the material of your enclosure and therefore how thick it is.

If your enclosure is a ballon, then the pressure will change.